# how to throw validation error

Tags: php, html, mysql

registration_from.php

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
       <head>
        <title>Register</title>
       </head>
       <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        Name: 
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <br/> <br/>
        Username: 
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <br/> <br/>
        Password:
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <br/> <br/>

        Email: 
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <br/> <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
  </html>
   <?php
  require('connect.php');
  require('validation.php');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

   if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if($query = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users 
 (`id`,`name`,`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES ('','".$name."', 
    '".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')")){
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        echo "Failure" . mysqli_error($connect);
      }
      }
 ?>
```

validation.php

```
     <?php
   // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $userErr = $passwordErr = "";
     $name =  $email = $username =$password = "";


     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
      } else {
       $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
       // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
       }
       }

      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
       } else {
      $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
       if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
       }
       }

        if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
      $userErr = "Username is required";
     } else {
      $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
     }

     if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
       $passwordErr = "Password is required";
     } else {
       $password= test_input($_POST["password"]);
      }

  }

   function test_input($data) {
     $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
    }
   ?>
```

connect.php

```
  <?php
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","php_forum") 
  or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connect)); 
    ?>
```

I'm developing a simple Registration from with four inputs i.e., Name, username, password, email.when the user fills out the form and click submit button then all the filled data should go n save in data base which is working fine in my case, but when the user wont fill any data and if user simply clicks a submit button then error message should be shown like "ALL FIELDS ARE NECESSARY", but where in my case even if i click submit button without entering any values the mesage i'm getting as success and all the null values are getting stored in the data base which should not happen, my output should be if i fill the forms n click submit button then all the data should be stored in database and if i click submit button without filling out any value then error should throw that "all field to be filled" and no null value should be stored in data base, please can any one guide me what changes i should do so that to get my desired output.

Comment: if you're using HTML 5 you can also add the builtin `required` attribute as an additional way to validate your inputs. [Check it here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind adding a little more code, you code do like:

In your **registration_form.php**

```
<?php
require('validation.php'); // Require first to do validation before queries
require('connect.php');

// Remove the part where you set variables to $_POST params
// Variables are already set inside validation.php

/**
* Then, I recommend moving queries to **connect.php**
* to have all your sql functions inside one file.
* Also moving the inserting of data to a function for easy grouping/calling
*/

if (isset($_POST["submit"]) {
    // Check if validation does not fail
    if ($emailErr == "" || $nameErr == "" || $userErr == "" || $passwordErr == "") {
        // Call to insert function
        doInsert($name, $email, $username, $password);
    } else {
        echo $emailErr . " " . $nameErr . " " . $userErr . " " . $passwordErr;
    }
}

?>
```

In your **connect.php**

```
function doInsert($name, $email, $username, $password) {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","php_forum")
        or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connect));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(`id`,`name`,`username`, `password`, `email`)
            VALUES ('','".$name."', '".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')";

    $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    if ($query) {
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Failure " . mysqli_error($connect);
    }
}
```

Comment: what about validation.php file??

Comment: Your validation.php is already checking if user inputs are supplied. So it's good

Comment: If it helps you, please accept or upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Please add error in session and print session in form file.

In validation.php

```
$nameErr = $emailErr = $userErr = $passwordErr = "";
$name =  $email = $username =$password = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 $name = $_POST["name"];
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $username = $_POST["username"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];

if($name == '' ||  $email == '' || $username == '' || $password == "") 
 {
  echo "ALL FIELDS ARE NECESSARY";
  exit();
 }

     if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
      } else {
       $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
       // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
       }
       }

      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
       } else {
      $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
       if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
       }
       }

        if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
      $userErr = "Username is required";
     } else {
      $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
     }

     if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
       $passwordErr = "Password is required";
     } else {
       $password= test_input($_POST["password"]);
      }

  }
```

registration_from.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION['error]) && !empty($_SESSION['error])){
   echo $_SESSION["error"]
 }
```

Comment: in validation file i have mentioned as empty right? then what is the necessary to use above code

Comment: Please see updated answer, you need to assign form value to your variable and then check for validation

Comment: actually i'm not getting what ur telling me

Comment: for what purpose u have used header in validation.php ??

Comment: sorry @priya what ur telling m not getting at all

Comment: header added for redirect to form page and show error in that page, if you not want to redirect then just echo message, please update

Comment: @Priya no need header() here

Comment: i did tried its not working, when i click submit button without entering any value its throwing an error, but when i check my data base then the null values are stored in the data base

Comment: Please add exit(); after echo message

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
  $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website">
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $website;
echo "<br>";
echo $comment;
echo "<br>";
echo $gender;
?>
```